# TKInter: update label on UI at a certain time

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to get a JSON file from an API and save it in a file. Then view it on a Raspberry Pi UI. My issue is that after I update the JSON file, the UI does not get updated.

Here is the code:

```
class Window(tk.Tk):

x = datetime.today()
y = x.replace(x.second+30 , hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
delta_t = y - x

secs = delta_t.seconds + 1
sched = BlockingScheduler()
root = tk.Tk()


def reading_APIfile(self):
    # getting current time.
    print("here is what is in " )
    current_time = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
    # open and read from json file
    # threading.Timer(10, self.reading_APIfile()).start()


    with open('JSONresponse.json') as a:
        json_dict = json.load(a)
       # print(current_time)
        self.locationDescription = json_dict['locationDescription']
        self.location = json_dict['name']
        for obj in json_dict['sessions']:
            for key in obj:
                if obj['stringStartTime'] <= current_time and obj['stringEndTime'] >= current_time:
                    self.qrCodeToken = obj['token']
                    self.startTime = obj['stringStartTime']
                    self.endTime = obj['stringEndTime']
                elif obj['stringEndTime'] <= current_time:
                    self.qrCodeToken = obj['token']
                    self.startTime = obj['stringStartTime']
                    self.endTime = obj['stringEndTime']
                for x in obj['courses']:
                    for key1 in x:
                        self.subject = x['subjectCode'] + " " + x['subject']
                        self.Name = x['className']


def __init__(self):
    # self.gettingAPI()
    self.reading_APIfile()
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.title("ODUATTAND")
    self.geometry('{}x{}'.format(660, 350))
    self.attributes('-zoomed', True)  # This just maximizes it so we can see the window. It's nothing to do with fullscreen.
    #self.frame = Frame(self.tk)
    #self.frame.pack()
    self.state = False
    self.bind("<F11>", self.toggle_fullscreen)
    self.bind("<Escape>", self.end_fullscreen)

    #Generat Qr code.

    big_code = pyqrcode.create(self.qrCodeToken, error='L')
    #print(self.qrcodetoken)
    big_code.png('code.png', scale=6, module_color=[0, 0, 0, 128], background=[0xff, 0xff, 0xff])

    # Main container
   # topleft = Frame(self, bg='white')
    btm_left = Frame(self, bg='white')
    top_right = Frame(self, bg='white')
    btm_right = Frame(self, bg='white')

    self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

    # old frame setting
    for r in range(6):
        self.grid_rowconfigure(r, weight=1)
    for c in range(5):
        self.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)

    # x= self.reading_APIfile.subject
    # print ("here is X" + x)
    #topleft.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 4, columnspan = 4, sticky = W+E+N+S)
    btm_left.grid(row = 0, column = 0, rowspan = 6, columnspan = 6, sticky = W+E+N+S)
    top_right.grid(row = 0, column = 3, rowspan = 4, columnspan = 3,padx=0, sticky = W+E+N+S)
    btm_right.grid(row = 2, column = 3, rowspan = 4, columnspan = 3, sticky = W+E+N+S)
    btm_right.grid(row=2, column=3, rowspan=4, columnspan=3, sticky=W + E + N + S)

    self.label1 = tk.Label(top_right, text= self.subject+ ": "+ self.Name +"\n" + self.location +"\n "+ self.startTime+ " "+ self.endTime)
    self.label1.place(x=190,y=45,anchor="center")
    self.label1.config(width=300, font=("Arial", 12), bg="white")

    # reading the card
    self.code = ''

    self.label = tk.Label(btm_right, text="PLease swipe your card")
    self.label.place(x=150, y=155, anchor="center")
    self.label.config(width=200, font=("Arial", 12), bg="white",padx=0)


    #if self.code !="":

    self.canvas = Canvas(btm_right, width=250, height=200, highlightthickn=0)
    self.canvas.place(x=120,y=40, anchor="center")
    tk_img = Image.open('check.png')
    check_img1=tk_img.resize((150,130), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    check_img2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(check_img1)
    panel = tk.Label(btm_right, image=check_img2)
    panel.image = check_img2
    self.x = self.canvas.create_image( 155, 125, image=check_img2)
    self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.x, state=tk.HIDDEN)
    self.canvas.configure(background='white')
    # self.label1.grid(row=2, column=2)


    self.bind('<Key>', self.get_key)

    #insert QR code
    Qrimage = Image.open('code.png')
    Qrimage1 = Qrimage.resize((400, 400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    Qrimage2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Qrimage1)
    # img=img.subsample(2,2)
    panel = tk.Label(btm_left, image=Qrimage2)
    panel.place(x=200, y=175, anchor="center")
    # panel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nw")
    panel.image = Qrimage2

    # insert a Logo
    path = "/home/mohamedshaaban/PycharmProjects/untitled1/986.gif"

    image = Image.open('986.gif')
    image1 = image.resize((100, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    image2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)
    # img=img.subsample(2,2)
    panel = tk.Label(btm_right, image=image2)
    panel.place(x=160, y=200, anchor="center" )
    panel.config(highlightthickness=0)
    # panel.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nw")
    panel.image = image2

    top_right.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    top_right.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    # self.th = threading.Timer(5.0,self.callinginit)
    print("here is what is 222 ")
    # self.callinginit()

    def callinginit(self):
        # self.__init__()
        self.reading_APIfile()
        print("it is working")
        # self.after(150000,self.callinginit())
```

I tried: `while true:
time.sleep()
schedule.every().day.at("06:00").do(callinginit, 'It is 06:00')` (but the issue it doesn't launch first time, have to wait till 6 am)

Answer (score 1):

Using `time.sleep()`, or a tight while loop blocks the execution of your GUI (it does not update).

The following example executes a piece of code every `interval` seconds.

The commented binding allows you to choose to execute the code immediately first, then wait for `interval` seconds to execute again; the default is to execute after `interval seconds`.

If you need to execute at a given time, you can modify it to first calculate how long between now and that time, and pass this value in seconds using the `interval` kwarg.

For long intervals, you can adjust the `root.after(5000, ...)` which calls `xeq_every` every 5 seconds to a larger value, maybe every 10 minutes, or every hour, depending how important it is to run on time.

It purposefully uses a kwarg with a mutable default value, to take advantage of the closure/memoization (depending on how you like to look at it) property.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time


def xeq_every(event, interval=25, memo=[None]):  
    if memo[0] is None:
        memo[0] = time.time() + interval
    elif memo[0] > time.time():
        print("waiting")   # replace with `pass`
    else:
        print("=======>> executing")
        memo[0] = time.time() + interval   # set the time of the next execution
    root.after(5000, xeq_every, 'dummy_event')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    next_time = tk.IntVar()
    next_time.set(f"will xeq at 25 seconds interval")
    lbl = tk.Label(root, textvariable=next_time)
    lbl.pack()

    # root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event, memo=[time.time()]: xeq_every(event, memo=memo))
    root.bind('<Button-1>', xeq_every)

    root.mainloop()
```

#### output:

```
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
=======>> executing
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
=======>> executing
waiting
waiting
waiting
waiting
=======>> executing
```

Comment: The issue when i use room.after in __init__, the UI didnt load. Why?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand `room.after in __init__`; what does it mean?

Comment: i add root.after(5000, __init__) in  def __init__(self)

Comment: Why? What makes you think it is a good idea to call `__init__` every 5 seconds? Sorry, I did not read your code, it is cluttered with stuff useless to the problem you asked. Maybe you should call the method that needs to be executed over an dover again, instead of `__init__`?

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood you but all my UI label is in __init__. thats why i was trying to do so.